# Backbone displaying nested json collections

Tags: javascript, json, backbone.js

Not sure where exactly I am going wrong. I cant seem to get the templates to render the title attributes within my nested json. I was following a tutorial online that was sort of holding my hand through this but I hit a brick wall and cant figure out why it wont render. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Here is my templates and html.

```
  <script id="albumTemplate" type="text/template">
     <p><%= title %></p>
  </script>
  <script id="subalbumTemplate" type="text/template">
     <p><%= title %></p>
  </script>

  <div class="row">
     <div class="six columns"><h5>Albums</h5></div>
     <div class="six columns"><h5>Sub-Albums</h5></div>
  </div>
  <div class="row" style="color: #333;">
     <div class="six columns" id="categories"></div>
     <div class="six columns" id="sub-cat"></div>
  </div>
```

Here is my app.js

```
        app.Subalbum = Backbone.Model.extend({
            initialize: function () {
                this.subId = this.get('id');
                this.subTitle = this.get('title');
                this.subImg = this.get('image');
                this.subCanvas = this.get('canvas');
                this.subSize = this.get('size');
            }
        });
        app.Subalbums = Backbone.Collection.extend({
            model: app.Subalbum
        });
        app.Album = Backbone.Model.extend({
            initialize: function () {
                this.subs = new app.Subalbums(this.get('subalbum'));
                this.subs.parent = this;
                this.albumId = this.get('id');
                this.albumTitle = this.get('title');
                this.albumImg = this.get('image');
            }
        });
        app.Albums = Backbone.Collection.extend({
            model: app.Album,
            url: 'albums.json',
            parse: function (data) {
                return data;
            }
        });

        app.AlbumCollectionView = Backbone.View.extend({
            el: $("#categories"),

            initialize: function () {
                _.bindAll(this, 'render');
                this.model.on('reset', function () {
                    this.render();
                }, this);
            },

            render: function (event) {
                _.each(this.model.models, function (album) {
                    //console.log(album.subs);
                    $(this.el).append(new app.AlbumView({
                        model: album
                    }).render().el);
                }, this);
                return this;
            }
        });

        app.AlbumView = Backbone.View.extend({
            template: _.template($("#albumTemplate").html()),
            initialize: function () {
                _.bindAll(this, 'render');
                // Subalbum View should be instantiated and called from inside the initialize function of the Parent View
                this.subView = new app.SubalbumView({
                    model: this.model.subs
                });
                this.subView.parentView = this; // this assignment connects the child view to the parent view
                $("#sub-cat").append(this.subView.render().el); // subView should "return this" from child render() function
            },
            render: function () {
                //console.log(this.model.subs);
                //$(this.el).html("<p>" + this.model.get("title") + "</p>");
                $(this.el).append(this.template(this.model.toJSON()));
                return this;
            }
        });

        app.SubalbumView = Backbone.View.extend({
            template: _.template($("#subalbumTemplate").html()),
            initialize: function () {
                _.bindAll(this, 'render');
                this.model.on('reset', function () {
                    this.render();
                }, this);
            },

            render: function (event) {
                _.each(this.model.models, function (subalbum) {
                    $(this.el).append("<p>" + subalbum.get("title") + "</p>");
                    //$(this.el).html(this.template(subalbum.toJSON()));
                }, this);
                return this;
            }
        });

        app.AlbumRouter = Backbone.Router.extend({
            routes: {
                "": "indexRoute"
            },
            indexRoute: function () {
                this.albumList = new app.Albums();
                this.albumList.fetch();
                this.albumAppView = new app.AlbumCollectionView({
                    model: this.albumList
                });
            }
        });

        var albumRoute = new app.AlbumRouter();
        Backbone.history.start();
```

Here is the albums.json file structure.

```
[
   {
      "pid":0,
      "title":"Blues Singer",
      "image":"blues_singer.jpg",
      "subalbum":[
         {
            "pid":0,
            "title":"Another Realm",
            "image":"another_realm.jpg"
         },
         {
            "pid":1,
            "title":"Ascendant",
            "image":"ascendant.jpg"
         },
         {
            "pid":2,
            "title":"Ascent",
            "image":"ascent.jpg"
         }
      ]
   },
   {
      "pid":1,
      "title":"Destiny",
      "image":"destiny.jpg",
      "subalbum":[
         {
            "pid":0,
            "title":"Cathedral of Trees",
            "image":"cathedral_of_trees.jpg"
         },
         {
            "pid":1,
            "title":"Come Up Here",
            "image":"come_up_here.jpg"
         },
         {
            "pid":2,
            "title":"Crystal Forest",
            "image":"crystal_forest.jpg"
         }
      ]
   },
   {
      "pid":2,
      "title":"Eagle",
      "image":"eagle.jpg",
      "subalbum":[
         {
            "pid":0,
            "title":"Curved Road",
            "image":"curved_road.jpg"
         },
         {
            "pid":1,
            "title":"Dawn Breaking",
            "image":"dawn_breaking.jpg"
         },
         {
            "pid":2,
            "title":"Dawn",
            "image":"dawn.jpg"
         }
      ]
   },
   {
      "pid":3,
      "title":"Evening Harvest",
      "image":"evening_harvest.jpg",
      "subalbum":[
         {
            "pid":0,
            "title":"Destiny",
            "image":"destiny.jpg"
         },
         {
            "pid":1,
            "title":"Destiny2",
            "image":"destiny2.jpg"
         },
         {
            "pid":2,
            "title":"Eagle Rising",
            "image":"eagle_rising.jpg"
         }
      ]
   }
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is you wait for the `reset` event from `this.albumList.fetch()`, however the `reset` isn't triggered by default, so you need to do pass `{reset:true}` to `fetch`. Here is a [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/J63AR/).

```
indexRoute: function () {
  this.albumList = new app.Albums();

  // This view will render when the model's reset event is triggered.
  // Since albumList is a collection, it should identified as such.
  this.albumAppView = new app.AlbumCollectionView({

    // albumList is a collection and it should identified as such.
    // instead of model:this.albumList - now within albumAppView, you will have
    // access to the collection via this.collection instead of this.model
    collection: this.albumList       
  });

  this.albumList.fetch({reset:true}); 
}
```

Some side suggestions (I'm going to pick on your `AlbumCollectionView`) but the same goes for your other views as well:

1. Instead of `el: $("#categories")` you can just use a string `el:'#categories'`
2. In `initialize`, You are using `this.model.on` when you could take advantage of [listenTo](http://backbonejs.org/#Events-listenTo). The main advantage of using `listenTo` is when call `remove` on a view, the event listeners are cleaned up for you.

   ```
   // this works.
   this.collection.on('reset', function () {
      this.render();
     }, this);

   // can be written as (remember the we changed model to collection above).
   this.listenTo(this.collection,'reset',this.render);
   ```
3. Moving onto your `render` function, a `Backbone.Collection` has a slew of [underscore methods](http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-Underscore-Methods) attached to them.

   ```
     // while this works
     _.each(this.collection.models, function (album) { ... });

     // can be written as:
     this.collection.each(function(album) { ... });
   });
   ```
4. `$(this.el)`, is sort of dated, you can use `this.$el`, which is just a cached jQuery object for the view's element. [$el documentation](http://backbonejs.org/#View-%24el).

So when we put it all together we wind up with:

```
app.AlbumCollectionView = Backbone.View.extend({
  el: '#categories',

  initialize: function () {
    this.listenTo(this.collection,'reset', this.render);
  },

  render: function () {
    this.collection.each(function (album) {
      var albumView = new app.AlbumView({model: album});
      this.$el.append(albumView.render().el);
      }, this);
    return this;
  }
});
```

Comment: Thank you so much! One of the best and most descriptive answers I've ever received on stack. It was also a nice bonus to receive some feedback on my code and different ways of going about doing things :)

Comment: Not sure if you could help me with one more thing or not, but I am trying to change the order that its rendering in. What I would like to see happen is have the [Album title]then [children of album title], then [NextAlbum title] then [children of album title] etc.

Comment: You mean like this http://jsfiddle.net/93mp9/? If so, this is because of the order you are `render`'ing your views.